# SharePoint REST api ODATA filter on nested array properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, odata

I am trying to call SharePoint REST api with $expand and would like to filter on inner array object in the JSON.  I tried few filter options but getting error for each of them.

Error:

> The expression "RoleAssignments/Member($filter=PrincipalType eq 8),RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings" is not valid.

Below is by API call:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list name>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,HasUniqueRoleAssignments,UniqueId,Id&$filter=FSObjType eq 1&$expand=RoleAssignments/Member($filter=PrincipalType eq 8),RoleAssignments/RoleDefinitionBindings
```

The JSON without filter as below that I woiuld like to filter on `RoleAssignments/Member/PrincipalType = 8`:

```
"value": [
{
    "RoleAssignments": [
        {
            "Member": {
                "PrincipalType": 8,
                "AllowMembersEditMembership": false,
                "AllowRequestToJoinLeave": false,
                "AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave": false,
            },
            "RoleDefinitionBindings": [
                {
                    "BasePermissions": {
                        "High": "107374520",
                        "Low": "10637219"
                    },
                    "Hidden": false,
                    "Id": 10737433925,
                    "Order": 0,
                    "RoleTypeKind": 0
                }
            ],
            "PrincipalId": 7
        },
        "Member": {
            "PrincipalType": 1,
            "AllowMembersEditMembership": false,
            "AllowRequestToJoinLeave": false,
            "AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave": false,
        },
        "RoleDefinitionBindings": [
            {
                "BasePermissions": {
                    "High": "1074342320",
                    "Low": "10637214r47"
                },
                "Hidden": false,
                "Id": 1073741999,
                "Order": 0,
                "RoleTypeKind": 0
            }
        ],
        "PrincipalId": 7
    ],
    "HasUniqueRoleAssignments": true,
    "Id": 6,
    "FileLeafRef": "Folder 1",
    "ID": 6,
    "FileRef": "/sites/testsite/Test Folder/Folder 1",
    "UniqueId": "632355e9-e559-48bf-8e6d-xxxxxxxxxx"
}
]
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to filter on inner array object using SharePoint REST API. You have to fetch all role assignments first and then filter returned result using JavaScript functions.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for your reply.  I am using this api in Power Automate.  Due to large JSON result i thought of filtering it in the API call itself

Comment: Do you know any better approach to filter the returned JSON in Power Automate?  It will be a huge help.. Thanks

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Filtering-an-array-of-objects-for-a-property-in-the-objects/td-p/718542